# Merge dataframes error: different variable type

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

When doing a merge between 2 dataframes in Python, I am having as error "ValueError: you are trying to merge on object anda float64 columns".
Is there a way to solve this **without** having to changing or converting the variable type of one of the dataframes? The idea of converting the variable is not an option to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [example]?

Comment: Sorry but I can't because, before creating the script with the merge, I want to know if it is possible to "jump" this error that i know i'm going to have performing a pd.merge.